# On cardinality of a set of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

What is the cardinality of the set of real valued continuous functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f(x)$ is rational whenever $x$ is rational?

I know that it's at least infinitely countably many because for any rational $q$, the contant function $f(x)=q$ on $[0,1]$ is in the set in question. Also, other functions like $f(x)=x^n$, for any integer $n$, are in this set.

But, what throws me at this point is my inability to infer whether there are other functions that make the set uncountable. If the case there aren't, how do I prove that it's only countably many?

Comment: Hint: use the intermediate value theorem

Comment: It may be helpful to think of this as the set of uniformly continuous functions from $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ to $\mathbb Q$. Such a function can be uniquely extended to a uniformly continuous function from $[0,1]$ (the completion of the domain) to $\mathbb R$ (the completion of the codomain), and conversely, any continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous and so restricts to a uniformly continuous function on $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

The cardinality of this set of functions $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathfrak{c}$, the continuum.

---

The cardinality of $\mathcal{F}$ is at least $\mathfrak{c}$ because given a real irrational number $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and any real number $\beta$, we can construct a function with the given properties and having $f(\alpha) = \beta$. In particular, if we fix $\alpha = 1/\sqrt{2}$ or your favorite irrational in the interval, this construction will describe as many different functions as there are real values for $\beta$, and $|\mathbb{R}| = \mathfrak{c}$.

Let $0 = a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < \cdots$ be any strictly increasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $\alpha$, and let $1 = b_1 > b_2 > b_3 > \cdots$ be any strictly decreasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $\alpha$. The function $f$ is:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\lfloor k \beta \rfloor}{k} + \left(\frac{\lfloor(k+1)\beta\rfloor}{k+1} - \frac{\lfloor k \beta \rfloor}{k}\right) \frac{x-a_k}{a_{k+1}-a_k} & a_k \leq x < a_{k+1} \\
\beta & x = \alpha \\
\frac{\lceil k \beta \rceil}{k} + \left(\frac{\lceil (k+1) \beta \rceil}{k+1} - \frac{\lceil k \beta \rceil}{k}\right) \frac{b_k-x}{b_k-b_{k+1}} & b_{k+1} < x \leq b_k
\end{cases} $$

$f(x)$ takes a rational value at every rational $x$, since all floor ($\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$) and ceiling ($\lceil \cdot \rceil$) function values are integers, $k$ is a positive integer, and all $a_k$ and $b_k$ are rational. $f$ is linear on the intervals $(a_k,a_{k+1})$ and $(b_{k+1},b_k)$, and continuity at the corner points $a_k$ and $b_k$ is easy to show. For continuity at $\alpha$, note that if $a_k \leq x < a_{k+1}$, since $f$ is linear on the interval,

$$ |f(x)-\beta| \leq \max(|f(a_k)-\beta|, |f(a_{k+1})-\beta|) $$
$$ |f(a_k)-\beta| = \left| \frac{\lfloor k \beta \rfloor}{k} - \beta \right| = \frac{k \beta - \lfloor k \beta \rfloor}{k} < \frac{1}{k} $$
$$ |f(x)-\beta| \leq \max \left(\frac{1}{k}, \frac{1}{k+1}\right) = \frac{1}{k} $$

Similarly, $b_{k+1} < x < b_k$ also implies $|f(x)-\beta| \leq \frac{1}{k}$. Since $j > k$ implies $1/j < 1/k$ and $f(\alpha)-\beta = 0$, it's also true that $|f(x)-\beta| \leq \frac{1}{k}$ for all $x \in [a_k,b_k]$. So for any real $\epsilon > 0$, choose positive integer $K > 1/\epsilon$, and  $|x-\alpha| < \min(\alpha-a_K, b_K-\alpha)$ implies $|f(x)-f(\alpha)| \leq 1/K < \epsilon$; $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$.

---

The cardinality of $\mathcal{F}$ is at most $\mathfrak{c}$ because we can define an injection from the set of functions to the set of sequences of rational numbers, which has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. This mapping is

$$ \Phi : f \mapsto \left(f(0), f(1), f\!\left(\frac{1}{2}\right), f\!\left(\frac{1}{4}\right), f\!\left(\frac{3}{4}\right), f\!\left(\frac{1}{8}\right), \ldots\right) $$

To show this $\Phi$ is injective, suppose $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous functions mapping to the same sequence. That is, $f_1\left(\frac{m}{2^n}\right) = f_2\left(\frac{m}{2^n}\right)$ for numbers of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ (with $m,n$ non-negative integers) in the domain. Suppose by way of contradiction that $f_1(x_0) \neq f_2(x_0)$ at any real $x_0 \in (0,1)$. Since each function is continuous, there exist a $\delta_1>0$ and $\delta_2>0$ such that

$$|x-x_0| < \delta_1 \implies |f_1(x)-f_1(x_0)| < \frac{1}{2}|f_1(x_0)-f_2(x_0)|$$
$$|x-x_0| < \delta_2 \implies |f_2(x)-f_2(x_0)| < \frac{1}{2}|f_1(x_0)-f_2(x_0)|$$

Let $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$. Since numbers of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ are dense, there is such a number $x_1 = \frac{m}{2^n}$ in the interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$. Then $|x_1-x_0| < \delta_1$ and $|x_1-x_0| < \delta_2$ and $f_1(x_1) = f_2(x_1)$, so combining the continuity statements with the triangle inequality gives

$$ \begin{align*} |f_1(x_0)-f_2(x_0)| &= \big|[f_1(x_0)-f_1(x_1)] - [f_2(x_0)-f_2(x_1)]\big| \\
&\leq |f_1(x_1)-f_1(x_0)| + |f_2(x_1)-f_2(x_0)| \\
&< \frac{1}{2}|f_1(x_0) - f_2(x_0)| + \frac{1}{2}|f_1(x_0)-f_2(x_0)| \\
&= |f_1(x_0)-f_2(x_0)|
\end{align*} $$

Contradiction: it is not possible that $f_1(x_0) \neq f_2(x_0)$. So if continuous functions have the same sequence $\Phi(f_1) = \Phi(f_2)$, the functions are identical; $\Phi$ is injective.

Comment: +1. Let $C[0,1]$ be the set of all continuous $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R.$ Any $f\in C[0,1]$ is uniquely determined by $f|_{\Bbb Q}$. So we have $|\mathcal F|\le |C[0,1]|\le |\Bbb R^{\Bbb Q}|=\mathfrak c$.

Comment: Yes, or I realized after that I could have just used for the sequence order an enumeration of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ instead of an enumeration of $m/2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous functions on $[0,1]$ are uniquely determined by their values on the countable dense set $D=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. That is, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous and if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in D$, then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Thus, there is an injective function $$\Phi: C([0,1],\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^D,$$ where $\mathbb{R}^D$ is the set of all functions $D\to\mathbb{R}$. Finally, $$card(\mathbb{R}) \leq card(C([0,1],\mathbb{R})) \leq card(\mathbb{R}^D) = card(\mathbb{R})^{card(D)} = card(\mathbb{R}).$$
Consequently, $card(\mathbb{R}) = card(C([0,1],\mathbb{R}))$.

---

**Edit:** I missed a crucial part of the question at the first look. Let $A\subseteq C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all continuous functions that map rationals to rationals.

Every continuous function defined on $I=[0,1]$ (generally on a compact set $I$) attains its minimum on $I$. It is not difficult to show that for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $f\in A$ with minimum value $a$. (Just consider polynomials with rational coefficients, or piecewise linear functions with a single kink.) Thus, there exists a surjective map $\Psi:A\to\mathbb{R}$. Consequently, $$card(\mathbb{R})\leq card(A).$$ Also, from above, $card(A)\leq card(C([0,1],\mathbb{R})) = card(\mathbb{R})$. Together, $card(\mathbb{R}) = card(A)$.

Comment: True, but the question here is about the subset of $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ that assigns only rational values to rational values.  Does this still have the same cardinality, or a smaller one?

Comment: @TobyBartels I was careless, thanks for the warning. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: A join of two lines in $A$ will have rational minimum. The minimum of a polynomial with rational coefficients is always an algebraic number. I agree we could construct a function with any real minimum, but not in those ways.

Comment: Yes, I believe that this works.  As @aschepler said, you can't get any minimum you like from a polynomial, but that's OK, because you can still get it from a piecewise-linear function approaching the minimum along a sequence of rational approximations.